# Is this database design correct?

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to represent this:

- A message can be sent to one or more recipients.
- A user (recipient) can receive zero or more messages (but he/she could receive a
  message only once).

Is my database design correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my question is YES. With this model, I can represent a message that could have only one recipient.

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031719/a-good-database-design-for-e-mail-or-private-message) and it has the same model than mine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In nutshell that what you are looking for.
You do need composite primary key "binding" those 2 FK in intersection table.
(all attributes are omitted for brevity)

USERS can receive zero - or - more messages
Messages can be sent to one - or - more users.

ps.

Tool i used to generate image is a bit buggy - line bewteen mail_box and Users should be dotted.

Comment: A message has a sender and one or more recipient. Where is the sender here?

Comment: I have updated my question with a better diagram.